# How to use Java 7+ 'Objects.hash()' with arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, java-7, hashcode

I really like Java 7+ style of writing `hashCode()` method:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    Objects.hash(field1, field2);
}
```

It doesn't work correctly with arrays though. The following code:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    Objects.hash(field1, field2, array1, array2);
}
```

will not work, as for `array1` and `array2` regular `hashCode()` instead of `Arrays.hashCode()` would be invoked.

How can I use `Objects.hash()` with arrays in a proper way?

Comment: You'd probably have to use `Arrays.deepHashCode`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - can you elaborate why may I need to use **deep** hash code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try:

```
Objects.hash(field1, field2, Arrays.hashCode(array1), Arrays.hashCode(array2));
```

This is the same as creating one array that contains `field1`, `field2`, the contents of `array1` and the contents of `array2`. Then computing `Arrays.hashCode` on this array.

Answer (score 7):

[`Arrays.deepHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepHashCode(java.lang.Object[])) will discover arrays in the array (via `instanceof Object[]`) and recursively call itself.
See the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.deepHashCode%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

> If the array contains other arrays as elements, the hash code is based on their contents and so on, ad infinitum.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    Object[] fields = {field1, field2, array1, array2};
    return Arrays.deepHashCode(fields);
}
```

It would be useful to have a params version like `Objects.hash`, but you'd have to write your own:

```
public final class HashUtils {
    private HashUtils(){}

    public static int deepHashCode(Object... fields) {
        return Arrays.deepHashCode(fields);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashUtils.deepHashCode(field1, field2, array1, array2);
}
```